# $ax+by+c=0$ in computer graphics

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, computer-science

I'm doing a course in computer graphics at the university.

We are talked about this Lineare Equation: $ax+by+c=0$ for $2D$ and of course the one for $3D$.

I don't really get it for what this equation is good for.
I already used some tools do visualize it and i think it was $45^\circ$ if $y, x$ and $c =0$, and if $c$ was something else the height of the line was shifted.

I also read something about intersection but I really don't get the concept of this equation in the sense of computer graphics.

Comment: A linear equation is quite good for describing a line.

Comment: $ax+by+c=0~$ is the general equation of a straight line. By varying $a,b,c$ you obtain various lines. In the same way, $ax+by+cz+d=0~$ is the general equation of a plane in 3d. That's it. The parameters define the relative position and orientation of different planes and lines. The absolute position and orientation depend on the **coordinate system** used

Comment: You should really read/study some introduction to **analytic geometry** which is the area of maths studying the connection between algebraic equations and geometric shapes. It's absolutely indispensable to know this stuff if you are planning to work with computer graphics

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will have a look at analytic geometry!